# winsock randomly refusing socket

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I've been trying to figure out how web-servers works and played around with the following code:

```
#include<io.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

# if defined(_MSC_VER)
# ifndef _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
# define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE (1)
# endif
# pragma warning(disable : 4996)
# endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;
    char *message;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    //Bind
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    while (1)
    {
        new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
        puts("Connection accepted");

        //Reply to client
        message =
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html\n"
            "Content-Length: 5\n"
            "\n"
            "sadasdsa";
        send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);


    }
    getchar();

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem occuring with this code is that ~every second connection got refused and randomly works.
I've tried to add `closesocket(new_socket)` and the end of the loop, but I didn't even received response at `localhost:8888`.

Comment: `accept()` should only be called from within the loop, and you should be resetting `c` before each call and checking for an error after each call, and closing each `new_socket` when done with it.